# How to aggregate by month given start date and end date?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I have a table `my_table` that resembles:

```
id    start_date    end_date   
1     2019-12       2021-12
2     2017-11       2019-03
3     2016-09       2018-09
```

I have another table `date_values` with every date like:

```
date_value
2016-09
2016-10
```

I want to get the output for every month:

```
month      num_people
2016-09    1
2016-10    1
```

How would I go about doing this?

I know I would need to GROUP BY month and then aggregate by COUNT(id), but I'm unsure of how to get the dates in the format I need. Would appreciate help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to `JOIN` on date range, using `BETWEEN`, but your DateTime isn't a valid format, we need to use `STR_TO_DATE` function converts the string to DateTime then compare

**Query 1**:

```
    SELECT t2.date_value,COUNT(*) num_people
    FROM my_table t1
    INNER JOIN date_values t2
    ON STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t2.date_value,'-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t1.start_date ,'-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t1.end_date ,'-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    GROUP BY t2.date_value
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fa478/2/0)**:

```
| date_value | num_people |
|------------|------------|
|    2016-09 |          1 |
|    2016-10 |          1 |
```

I would suggest `date_value`,`start_date`, `end_date` might be DateTime type instead of string type.

if you want to show `DATE_FORMAT` data in `yyyy-MM` format, we can use `DATE_FORMAT` function.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m')
```